# CSS imported in a SVG file ignored by Internet Explorer when served through Vaadin Request Handler

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg, vaadin

I have a Vaadin widget for displaying svg-files. These svg-files can import css-files and images. The css-file in turn can, in addition to styles, also reference some font files.

To serve all of these files, I implemented a custom Vaadin RequestHandler and added it to the session.

To include the svg in my widget, I tested multiple things: For Firefox and Chrome, embedding the svg as the src of an iframe works fine. I also tried the jquery-addon jquery-svg, no problems here either.

However, on Internet Explorer (I used IE11 and also tried compatibility modes down to IE9), both approaches lead to the same problem:
The svg is loaded correctly. All images are loaded correctly. The css-files are requested and served correctly, I checked the response and it is as expected. However, the CSS content is completely ignored. Neither are there any further requests for the referenced font-files, nor are the css rules in the file applied at all.

I tested putting the same svg-file with its resources on the server as static resources (e.g. in the VAADIN-folder), or in their own context, and the content is loaded just fine on all browsers, the problem only occurs when providing the files through the session RequestHandler.

I also tried copying the contents of the css-file into the svg-file itself, without an @import. Again this works fine, even with the RequestHandler, but I would rather keep the css and the svg split.

Does anyone here have some experiences with this or has run into similar problems?

Thanks,

Matthias

Comment: You should compare the http requests/responses from the static and the vaadin version, there must be a difference somewhere. Most probably the vaadin version has some different paths...

Comment: @AndréSchild Thanks, I must have missed the missing contentType the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue by comparing the responses: The contentType of the response was missing. It's set automatically for static resources, but I had to do it manually in the Vaadin Request Handler.
(Thanks André)